# mmap writes to file on disk(synchronous/asynchronous)

Tags: mmap, synchronous

I havea question regarding mmap functionality. when mmap is used in asynchronous mode where the kernel takes care of persisting the data to the mapped file on the disk , is it possible to have the former updates overwrite the later updates ?

Lets say at time T, we modify a location in memory that is memory mapped to a file on disk and again at time T+1 we modify the same location in memory. As the writes to the file are not synchronous, is it possible that kernel first picks up the modifications at time T+1 and then picks up the modifications at time T resulting in inconsistency in the memory mapped file ?

Comment: Specifying the OS might help.

Comment: In general, no. Writes are buffered to the page (or filesystem) cache, writing to the same location twice means the data is written to the same RAM location. Hence the problem you describe isn't likely, as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly possible. The file *is* allowed to be inconsistent till **msync(2)** or **munmap(2)** - when that happens, *dirty* (modified) pages are written to disk page by page (sometimes more, depends on filesystem in newer kernels). msync() allows you to specify synchronous operation and invalidation of caches after finished write, which allows you to ensure that the data in **cache** is the same as data in file. Without that, it's possible that your program will see newer data but file contains older - exact specifics of the rather hairy situation depend on CPU architecture and specific OS implementation of those routines.